# VirtualBox delete the virtual machine after I saved the state of VM and restarted

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I save the machine state and then restarted the VirtualBox on windows machine. My guest OS in LUnuntu and my host in Windows 7. I saved the state of my VM yesterday and when I started the VM today it showed me he welcome message saying:

`The left part of this window is a list of all virtual machines on your computer. The list is empty now because you haven't created any virtual machines yet.`

I can't understand why a virtual machine got deleted? It might be that saving the state of VM corrupted the VM. Even if its corrupted, shouldn't it just reboot normally without restoring the state?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you didn't wait for VirtualBox to create the file before you closed it.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound for our comment. So does that mean that while saving the state, VM saves some stuff on the same file which it uses for booting up?

Comment: Are the VM files still there? Even if it got corrupted, the files should still be there. They would not automaticlly be deleted.

Comment: @JerryOL - I am just guessing the file was created. Search your hdd for the file to see if it even it exists.  If the process of creating the file wasn't finished then the file more then likely does not exist.

Comment: Yes, thankfully the VM files are still there. So I created a new virtual machine using the same virtual disk image and now everything is fine. I was curious to know the reason behind why this happened. Even is the state was corrupt, why won't it recognize the existence of a machine. I know that from next time, either I should just shut it down or completely wait for the VM to save the state. Sorry if I am being too nube but was just curious to know the reason.

Comment: No apologies needed.  That's how we learn.